# Change Device Name on Family Link Device

Tags: google-play-store, settings, parental-control, google-family-link, device-name

I'm wondering how to change a device name for a device/account supervised by Family Link.

I've changed the actual device name in the devices settings but the device name that shows up in Google / GooglePlay / FamilyLink is controlled by Google Play. To change THAT name you need to do it on the settings page of Google Play. This only works on the Google Play website. If I try to access the supervised account via a browser it says this account must access play through the app only. I assume this is because store restriction can really only be handled through the controlled app?. Either way the device list is not available in the play app and thus there is no where to rename the device.

Any advice? Is there anyway I could access the web version of the settings page through the play app?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're able to rename the device from [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/find) page. Log in with your child's account on a web browser and then modify the device name.